# How to configure 100% image using nextJS <Image />?

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js

After upgrade nextJS to the latest version I do get some errors using `Image`:

```
// import Image from 'next/image'
<div style={Object.assign({}, styles.slide, style)} key={key}>
  <Image
    src={src}
    alt=""
    width={100 + '%'}
    height={100 + '%'}
    objectFit="cover"
  />
</div>
```

1. 'objectFit' is deprecated
2. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'SafeNumber'

Which is the correct way to configure the image as 100% width and height?

Comment: I believe width and height needs to be the actual width and height of image, in pixels. You may then use css to stretch the image full width and also specify object fit cover over there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why Nextjs has made it quite hard to use 100% for width and height of an image. A solution which worked for me is this one:

```
<div style={{ width: "100%", height: "300px", position: "relative" }} >
  <Image src={Your_image} alt="Hero-image" fill />
</div>
```

> This will give you 100% width but you have to adjust height yourself, I guess `height: 100%` here might also work here but I can't say for sure.

If you wanna change the object-fit for the image, You might have to use a classname or inline-style as ObjectFit prop is deprecated in Next v13 (I suppose it does that on its own now)

```
<Image src={Your_image} alt="Hero-image" fill style={{ objectFit: "cover" }} />
```

Answer (score 1):

I migrated from nextjs 12 to 13. I run `npx @next/codemod@latest next-image-to-legacy-image ./pages` and then `npx @next/codemod@latest next-image-experimental ./pages` and got the same error `Type '"523px"' is not assignable to type 'SafeNumber | undefined'.` However, an inline style was added automatically.

```
style={{
         maxWidth: '100%',
         height: 'auto',
      }}
```

Hence, I say this is the way to set the width and height.

Answer (score 0):

Set `width` to `100%` in `styles` property:

```
  <Image
    src={src}
    alt=""
    width={width}
    height={height}
    style={{ width: '100%', height: 'auto' }}
  />
```

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'SafeNumber'

Make sure you are passing a valid `Number`